# Authenticate against EJB via RESTeasy webservice

Tags: authentication, jboss, resteasy

I am trying to setup a REST-webservice with RESTeasy that access EJBs that are deployed on a JBoss 7.1.1.
I've been successful in:

- Setting up Beans to be accessed via REST
- Configuring SSL for the connection
- Setting up a PreProcessInterceptor that uses HTTP Basic Auth to ask the User for his credentials.

Currently I basically just check the credentials hardcoded in the interceptor.
This works to make sure that the User is authenticated, but our Beans query for the name of the currently logged in Principal for some Beancalls like this:

```
@Resource
private SessionContext context = null;
[...]

String userName = context.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
```

Currently userName is now always anonymous. What is the right way to set the caller principal? Do I do this in an Interceptor? Or in the Bean itself? My goal is to basically be able to call a method loginUserWithEJBOnJboss(String user, String pass) that uses the login-methods that are configured within the jboss and sets the principal correctly.

I am at a loss here, google didn't find anything. Maybe I am just searching for the wrong words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah, as always soon after asking I find the solution myself. I think sometimes I only ask because I know this will happen.

So the solution are these methods:

```
    SecurityContextAssociation.setPrincipal(new SimplePrincipal(username));
    SecurityContextAssociation.setCredential(password.toCharArray());
```

They do pretty much all I wanted :)